# Get Req and Res variables at anytime with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, function, sockets, express

Is there any way to get access to the 'req' and 'res' variables from:

```
app.get('/',  function(req, res) {
    console.log('ok');
});
```

after the page loading with NodeJS ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain a little better what do you want? In each request made, you will have access to the req and the res variables just like you posted

Comment: I would like to get access to those variables but after the request, without creating collisions between clients..

Comment: What's the point on accessing those variables after the request is finished? Anyway, you can store it as cookies or even in a database, despite I don't understand your goal

Comment: Because I need my browser to show them, it's like 'username', or 'steamid' variables...

Comment: So, in your requests, you can just use res.send(req.params) and your params variables will be sent to the browser

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to use them with my browser (in html/js)...

Comment: You have to use some library to perform the requests, what are you using? jquery? react/vue/angular? Explain me a little more how are you doing the request with an example if possible

Comment: Thank you for your support :)       I'm using NodeJS (with a steam login librairy), and I want to send to the client a custom page (with name,...) after being connected via steam.
But in the example file, it's: "res.send(req.user == null ? 'not logged in' : 'hello ' + req.user.username).end();" and I modify it to send an HTML file with "res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/main.html'));".    But like that, I don't know how to send data (req.user.username variable). I'm using JQuery, but not react, vue or Angular. All I want is to send simple data to the HTML page during the request. Thanks :)

Comment: So, your jquery request should be something like
$.ajax({
        url: "localhost:8080/hello",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', // added data type
        success: function(yourData) {
            console.log(yourData);
        }
    });


And in the backend something

app.get('/hello', (req, res, next)) {
      res.send(req.user == null ? 'not logged in' : 'hello ' + req.user.username)
}

Comment: But with this configuration, how to send the main HTML file (index.html) ? Because it's not sending an HTML page but just 'not logged in' and 'hello ...'  Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry man, I really don't understand what is happening, can you put on github your code for me to analyze?

Comment: Sorry for the delay :)    Is it possible to talk on discord ? (Ezzcargot#7985)